# Hide Div When Content == "0" Using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to write a script that checks the content of a div, and if that content is exactly 0 than it hides the div. This is for an inbox system so that the count only shows if you have a new message. This is what I wrote:

```js
var count = $('.count').val();
if (count == '0') {
  $('.count').hide();
} else {
  $('.count').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='index.php?act=UserCP&CODE=alerts'>
  <span class="count"><!-- |new_alerts| --></span> alerts</a>
<a href='index.php?act=Msg&CODE=01'>
  <span class="count"><!-- |new_msg| --></span> inbox</a>
```

[Site Where the Problem is Occurring.](https://colourcoded.jcink.net/index.php?act=idx)

The `<!--|new_msg| -->` is part of the hosting site's user menu system. On the site it changes to a number, correlating to how many new alerts or new messages you have. Is this the reason? The div has an actual number on the site, so it should read that right?

Comment: `.val()` is for inputs. `.text()` is for divs.

Comment: Div's don't have values so the `val()` method won't give you the content you are looking for, use `text()` or `html()`

Comment: ah, okay, i've changed that, but now it just doesn't hide anything.

Comment: Add your HTML, make it executable with a Stack Snippet.

Comment: added my html and a link to the site where the problem is. i don't know how to make a stack snippet though? sorry.

Comment: trying to understand more - you want to hide the whole alerts and inbox `a` tag when the count class is `0` counter for inbox and alerts ?

Comment: no, not the whole a tag, just the count itself. So that if it reads 0 inbox, than it hides the 0. I'm guessing that the code itself works but that something is interfering with the way the host site sets up the message, like because in the HTML i have ```<!--|new_msg| -->``` its reading that and not the 0 that is produced from that.

Comment: Yes, i understand that way my answer i posted shouild have worked. But i think the site is still overwriting the 0 in your span count.

Comment: If I make it a function that is executed onload would that potentially fix this? Does that make sense, ```var count = $('.count').val();
function hideNoNew(){
if(count == '0'){
 $('.count').hide();
} else { $('.count').show();}
}
$('.count').onload = function(){hideNoNew()};``` it doesn't work, so I'm assuming I'm not writing it right?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out why but I have zero luck getting class selectors to work. Try setting an id on the element. And then...

```
var count = $(document).getElementById("#countId").textContent;
if (count == '0') { 
    $(document).getElementById("#countId").style.display = 'none'; 
} 
else { 
    $(document).getElementById("#countId").style.display = ''; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've multiple `.count` elements this is exactly what `count` variable will return <sup>[See The Next Code]</sup>.. And for sure it will not match `0` at all

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = $(".count").text().trim();
  console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">0</span>
<span class="count">1</span>
<span class="count">2</span>
```

The right way is to loop through the `.count` elements using `.each` or even `.filter`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".count").show(0).filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim() == 0;
  }).hide(0); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">0</span>
<span class="count">1</span>
<span class="count">2</span>
```